# How to use UWP NavigationView back button without reloading the page

Tags: uwp

I am new to UWP. I am working on migrating a WPF application to UWP. My current problem is in navigation. When I go to a page and try to go back to the previous page, the page reloads. How can I avoid this behavior? I need to go back to the previous page as it was when the second page was called.
Thanks in advance for your help.

```
<Page
x:Class="WeCanSpeak.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:WeCanSpeak"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

<Grid>
    <NavigationView x:Name="nvvMain" PaneDisplayMode="LeftCompact" IsBackEnabled="True" IsSettingsVisible="False" BorderThickness="1" IsPaneOpen="False" BackRequested="NvvMain_BackRequested">
        <NavigationView.MenuItems>
            <NavigationViewItem x:Name="nviHistory" Icon="Clock" Content="Histórico" />
            <NavigationViewItem x:Name="nviDictionary" Icon="Library" Content="Dicionário" />
            <NavigationViewItem x:Name="nviHelp" Icon="Help" Content="Ajuda" />
            <NavigationViewItem x:Name="nviSettings" Icon="Setting" Content="Configurações"  Tapped="NviSettings_Tapped" />
            </NavigationView.MenuItems>
        <Frame x:Name="NavigationFrame" />
    </NavigationView>
</Grid>
```

```
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        NavigationFrame.Navigate(typeof(SpeakPage));
    }

    private void NviSettings_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        NavigationFrame.Navigate(typeof(SettingsPage));
    }

    private void NvvMain_BackRequested(NavigationView sender, NavigationViewBackRequestedEventArgs args)
    {
        NavigationFrame.GoBack();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Page content and state is not cached by default, when you go back to the previous page, it will become initial state. So if you want to cache information without reloading, you need to enable it in the page which you don't want to reload. For more information about this, you can refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/basics/navigate-between-two-pages#4-cache-a-page).

```
public MyPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    this.NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Enabled;
}
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thank you very much, @Faywang.